# How to call an a component from other angular application component - nginx configuration missing?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, certificate

My current problem is, I have two angular applications since those have different configurations and styles anyway, however my problem is that I wanted to call or route one of the application to the other through nginx using proxy reverse and SSL, actually I have my configuration over two config files, but when one is trying to call the other I am getting an error such as route error, I don't know if is part of the angular side or Nginx side, does anyone can help to me on this?, I'll post an a example how I have my structure.

- Config one

  server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  ```
          server_name _;

          return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } server {  
                    listen 443;
             listen [::]:443;
             root /var/www/html/;

             ssl on;
             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.crt;
                    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

                    server_name example.com;
                    location / {  
                                 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;  
                                 proxy_http_version 1.1;  
                                 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
                                 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
                                 proxy_set_header Host $host;  
                                 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                     } }
  ```
- Config two

  server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  ```
      server_name _;

      return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } server {  
                listen 443;
         listen [::]:443;
         root /var/www/html/;

         ssl on;
         ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

                server_name example.com;
                location /login {  
                             proxy_pass http://localhost:8089;  
                             proxy_http_version 1.1;  
                             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
                             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
                             proxy_set_header Host $host;  
                             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                 } }
  ```

**Angular:**

***APP Route configuration 1***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component:LayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'home', component:HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'about', component:AboutComponent,
      },
      {
        path:'digital', component:DigitalComponent
      },
      {
        path:'documents', component:DocumentsComponent
      },
      {
        path:'contact', component:ContactUsComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {path:'test', component:HomeComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/home'},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***APP Route Configuration 2***

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '',component:SignInComponent},
  { path: 'login',component:SignInComponent},
{path: '404', component: ErrorTemplateComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'},


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You should add your route configurations as code, not as screenshots.

Comment: OK let me change it